# Setting seeds for parametric min cuts

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I was just trying to implement this paper : [www.isr.uc.pt/~joaoluis/papers/PAMI2012.pdf](http://www.isr.uc.pt/~joaoluis/papers/PAMI2012.pdf).
For the first part - generating the figure ground hypothesis, setting foreground and background seeds is necessary. They have mentioned clearly that the background seeds should be put along the image edges, but for the foreground part they have just said - " alternate set of pixels are hypothesized to belong to foreground ". No mention of size or number of pixels. I have generated a graph and randomly considered the foreground pixels but with no success in final output.

What am I missing?...thanks

Comment: i think there is source code in here http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklth/personal/sminchis/code/cpmc/index.html

Comment: i implementing it in c++. Matlab code is greek to me

Comment: _greek_ can be very useful :D

Comment: Though OpenCV is great for production, Matlab is much better for learning faster. @Miki comment is right. This is from a OpenCv and C++ lover.